# i save the old element of the array in the new array. how can i fix this problem?

Tags: c, file, struct, scanf, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX (10)

struct parola{
   char parola1[MAX+1];
   char parola2[MAX+1];
   char parola3[MAX+1];
};

struct parola2{
   char parola1x[MAX+1];
   char parola2x[MAX+1];
   char parola3x[MAX+1];
};

struct parola *leggi_file(FILE *fp, int *count){
   int dim = 16;
   int j;
   struct parola *v, *v2;
   int conv = 0;
   char buf[1024];

   if(!(v = malloc(dim *sizeof(*v)))){
       free(v);
       puts("non va");
   }

   while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL){
       v2 = v + (*count);

       conv =
       sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s", v->parola1, v->parola2, v->parola3);
           printf("\n%s ", v[*count].parola1);
           printf("%s ", v[*count].parola2);
           printf("%s\n", v[*count].parola3);

       if(*count >= dim){
           dim *= 2;
           if(!(v = realloc(v, sizeof(*v)*dim))){
               free(v);
               return NULL;
           }
       (*count)++;
       }
   }
   return v;
}

void visual(struct parola *v, int count){
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<count; i++){
       printf("%s %s %s\n", v[i].parola1,v[i].parola2,v[i].parola3);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int count= 0;
   struct parola *v;
   
   FILE *fp;
   fp= fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (fp != 0){
   } else{
       return 1;
       }
   
   if(!(v = leggi_file(fp, &count))){
       return 0;
   }
   
   visual(v,count);
}
```

the program should read from ./a.out "file1.txt" a file with 3 words per line (not mandatory), and i need to save it on a struct "parola". my problem is that i cant make it in the right way.
*after the save, i will need to work on the single words of the struct, like modification ecc.

the file is like:
word1 word2 word3 (\n)
word4 word5 (\n)
word6 word7 word8 (\n)

but if i save, it should be the same, but if i visualize it, i receive:
word1 word2 word3 (\n)
word4 word5 word3 (\n)
word6 word7 word8 (\n)

Comment: I recommend you use your editor to reindent your code, and  one problem should become quite obvious. As would it have been if you tried to step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Use the return value of `sscanf()`, ie `conv` ... `conv = sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s", v->parola1, v->parola2, v->parola3); if (conv > 0) printf("\n%s ", v[*count].parola1); if (conv > 1) printf("\n%s ", v[*count].parola2); if (conv > 2) printf("\n%s ", v[*count].parola3);`

Comment: Do you want the output to be same as the text in `file1.txt`? Why don't you just print whatever you read until `EOF`?

Comment: <O/T> no point in having an empty `if` condition, just do `if (fp == NULL) { return 1; }`

Comment: <O/T> if `malloc` fails, there's no point in calling `free` on the returned NULL pointer, that operation is a noop.

Comment: To continue the `malloc` point of @yano, if `realloc` fails and return a null pointer you loose the original pointer and can't free it. Always use a temporary variable for the result of `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of major problems:

1. As alluded to in the first comment about poor indentation, you're updating `count` in the wrong place.  This should happen unconditionally, not only when `count > dim`.  Also, as pointed out by @SomeProgrammerDude, you're not handling `realloc` correctly.  You must use a temp variable in case it fails.

```c
if(*count >= dim){
    dim *= 2;
    struct parola* temp = realloc(v, sizeof(*v)*dim);
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
      // realloc successful, we can assign temp to our pointer now
      v = temp;
    }
    else
    {
      // uh oh, realloc failed, it looks like if this happens you just
      // want to bomb out
      free(v);
      return NULL;
    }
}
(*count)++;
```

2. You're calculating the next position in `v` with `v2` (`v2 = v + (*count);`), but neglecting to use it when you store the current line in the file in your `v` structure, so you continue to overwrite the strings at `v[0]`.  Instead, change the `sscanf` line to

```c
conv = sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s", v2->parola1, v2->parola2, v2->parola3);
```

Furthermore, you aren't checking/using the return value `conv` for anything useful.  As suggested by the comment, this should guide what you print:

```c
conv = sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s", v2->parola1, v2->parola2, v2->parola3);
if (conv >= 1) printf("\n%s ", v[*count].parola1);
if (conv >= 2) printf("%s ", v[*count].parola2);
if (conv == 3) printf("%s", v[*count].parola3);
printf("\n");
```

Since your structures are all strings, might be best to use `calloc` to allocate memory, giving you `NUL` terminators for free.

```c
if(!(v = calloc(dim, sizeof(*v)))){
   // if you get here, v is NULL, so no need to call free(v), that is a no-op.
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Me4b7sMYE) Using `stdin` instead of a file, and after cleaning up unused variables and structures.